# Acceder a objetos creados en otra clase, ¿De que forma?

Tags: c#, poo, xaml

Intento hacer lo siguiente...
En la vista principal `MainWindow` genero tanto objetos `ConfigNivel` como me hagan falta, estos objetos son unas vistas que alojaran posteriormente otros objetos de la clase `ConfigNivel` (otras vistas con opciones dentro de estas) en la cual se crearan otros objetos con propiedades que se cambien a través de `TextGroups`.
¿De alguna manera podria acceder a todas las propiedades de todos los objetos que he ido creando en las diferentes vistas desde el MainWindow?

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private void ConstruirFilas(int numFilas)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < numFilas; i++)
            {
               StackConfiguracion.Children.Add(new ConfigNivel(i));              
            }
        }
    }



 public partial class ConfigNivel : UserControl
      {
          private void Click_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              spElemento.Children.Clear();
              switch (CB_SeleccionGrupo.SelectedIndex)
              {
                  case 0:
                      spElemento.Children.Add(new Grupos.cuPotencia());
                      break;
                  case 1:
                      spElemento.Children.Add(new Grupos.cuManiobra());
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      spElemento.Children.Add(new Grupos.cuPLC());
                      break;
                  case 3:
                      spElemento.Children.Add(new Grupos.cuBornero());
                      break;
              }            
           }
       }
```

Con una imagen igual esta mas claro, dependiendo de las selecciones de los `ComboBox` se crean unos objetos u otros.
Si no esta claro lo editare.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Todo lo que pides se puede hacer con propiedades y eventos.. y sobre todo con un modelo MVVM que soporte todo esto. Igual seria mas facil si construis un [mcve] para que podamos trabajar, porque no se de donde queres acceder a donde y porque (no tiene sentido que el padre modifique las cosas de los hijos, deberia avisarle a los hijos que paso algo y que ellos se encarguen...)

Comment: Básicamente se trata de sumar todos los texbloc que está en la última columna, la que dice "Tamaño total" , así que a todas estas columnas debo acceder desde el MainWindow

Comment: Porque? porque cada objeto no puede disparar un evento cuando ocurra un cambio y la pantalla principal pedirles a cada uno que informe cual es el total de cada uno? me parece una arquitectura mucho mas robusta, si no todo termina dependiendo de todo. Si usaras MVVM  le podrias preguntar a VM el total..

Comment: Me voy a poner con patrones y mvvm, no quiero hacer chapuzas... pensaba que sería más sencillo hacerlo sin saber mvvm. Muchas gracias por el consejo, intentaré ponerme en cuando pueda

Comment: aunque no uses MVVM, cada objeto hijo debe informarte el total en alguna propiedad/variable, no debes ir y seguir su lista de objetos hijos para encontrar los valores.

Comment: Coincido con @gbianchi lo mejor es que utilices MVVM y el acceder a los campos de objetos hijos se va a convertir en una tarea más bien trivial. Puedes revisar el siguiente enlace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx

Comment: Un apunte, estoy mirando sobre MVVM y si, esta bien pensado lo de pasar datos de la vista al modelo y viceversa con el viewmodel pero... yo tengo los controles en vistas que se van creando dinamicamente, cargando objetos (UserControl, vistas con opciones), estando estas fuera del acceso del MainWindow...
Los ejemplos del mvvm que veo son para enlazar la parte del XAML con la del C# pero tratandose siempre de los elementos en la misma clase...
Si lo que quiero es intercambiar datos con vistas que no tienen nada que ver?

Comment: No se si mi ultima aportación es un poco desorbitada...Supongo que en casi cualquier aplicación es necesario acceder a propiedades de diferentes objetos que no se han instanciado en dicha clase, ¿Es asi?

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de  gbianchi, es la mejor para comprensión futura de lo que hace la aplicación. Dicho esto encontrar objetos de un tipo especifico en una colección seria de la siguiente forma;

```
  var collecionConfigNivel =StackConfiguracion.Children.OfType<ConfigNivel>()

  foreach(var configNivel in result)
        {
            var colleccioncuPotencia = configNivel.spElemento.Children.OfType<Grupos.cuPotencia>();

            foreach (var cuPotencia in colleccioncuPotencia)
            {
                var propieddA = cuPotencia.propiedadA;
            }
        }
```

lo puedes meter en un método y hacerlo recursivo si conoces el tipo común de los contenedores para recorrer todos los hijos.